# Trying to find vehicles which are free between 2 variable dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find out which, if any, vehicles are free between a pair of user input variables as dates.

Each vehicle, which is being used for a trip, has a start and end date in its row for when the trips starts and ends, therefore the vehicle is unavailable.

So far I pretty much get every listed registration instead of any kind of filtered results.

```
SELECT  vehicle_registration FROM 
(select vehicle_registration
FROM trips
WHERE departure
 not BETWEEN :departure AND :return
and return 
not BETWEEN :departure AND :return)
group by vehicle_registration
```

Any clues what I'm missing please?

Comment: Just a minor point, but you could include the group by in the main query rather than having two selects. Doesn't answer your question, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using AND, which implies both conditions have to be true. You need to use OR instead:

```
select vehicle_registration
  from trips
 where departure not between :departure and :return
    or return not between :departure and :return
```

On a side not, as indicated by the syntax highlighting, `return` is a *bad* name from a column name. It's a reserved word in Oracle and you should avoid it if you can.

Comment: Ah, yeah I did notice it was highlighted in Oracle, never clicked why.Thanks!  I used AND because they do have to be true? As in NOT here AND NOT here?

Comment: No, it's or because you can't rent out a vehicle if either one is true as it won't be there.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, although I may have got the >= mixed up. Assuming a vehicle table and vehicle_id being the primary key/foreign key:

This method has the added benefit of showing vehicles that haven't yet been booked for a trip.

```
Select
  v.*
From
  vehicle v
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select
      'x'
    From
      trips r
    Where
      r.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id and
      :return >= r.departure and
      :departure <= r.return
)
```